# Powershell can't see variables through wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, powershell, azure, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell script that creates an azure vm and installs Microsoft Dynamics Nav on the server and much more. The Script sets a bunch of variables and then calls subscripts.

I can call this script from C# through a pipeline and there are NO problems. Virtual machine gets created and everything.

But there is a major issue if I make a WCF client and Service and the Service creates the pipeline and executes the script.

Somehow the subscripts don't know all the variables.

In short: How comes that my script works perfect if the call comes directly from a console program but doesn't if the call comes through wcf?

Ps: it is not an issue concerning rights because the wcf service is IIS hosted and runs under an admin account.

This is how I call the script in both wcf and directly project.

```
        string path = "absolute path to script.ps1"
        Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runSpace.Open();
        try
        {
            RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runSpace);
            runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
            Pipeline pipeLine = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

            Command myCommand = new Command(path);
            param = new CommandParameter("some value","some value")
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
            pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand);

            var results = pipeLine.Invoke();                
            runSpace.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            runSpace.Close();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not used to powershell, but for those who may help you it would surely be helpful to add some code to your question.

Comment: The problem is that the script works perfect if you call it directly from a project. there are also no problems if you open the script in powershell ISE (the editor from Microsoft) and run it from there. The problem is that the subscripts have no acces to the Global variables.The code for calling the script directly and through wcf are identical. The only difference is that one call is directly to the script and the other through a wcf service.

Comment: It *might* be helpful to include the code you use to spawn the Powershell script. For both the C# and WCF